# Std::vector in Cython

Tags: cython

In `C++` I can declare a vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> array(size);
```

In `Cython` I can only do it this way:

```
cdef vector[int]* v = new vector[int](10)
```

When trying the following, it gives me an error:

```
cdef vector[int] v(10)
```

Is this not possible in `Cython` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is limitation is explicitly stated in the "wrapping c++" section of the Cython documentation.

Comment: @DavidW I couldn't that limitation mentioned in the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html)--could you kindly post a permalink please? Also, stack allocation like `cdef vector[int] v = vector[int](10)`  works for me, which seems to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: @YiboYang I can't either now. I'm not sure if things have changed or if the comment was unhelpful at the time (hopefully not the latter...). The limitation is that anything that anything that is stack allocated is default constructed at the start of the function (i.e. you can't call any constructor for stack allocated stuff). Your suggestion works. It relies on the object being copyable/movable and default constructable (OK in this case but not _always_ true) and there may (sometimes) be a performance cost for doing both the default construction, and the copy/move.

Answer (score 0):

```
cdef vector[int] v = range(10)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.